# Microsoft speech recognition api

Tags: authentication, speech-recognition, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I want to ask a bit about Authentication of this API
Do "The token" of the response have some expired time or something? or is it for eternity?

Documentation link is here :
https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition#Authorize

Comment: Since it's a JWT, if it's not encrypted and just signed, you should be able to [decode](https://jwt.io/) it and see if it contains an `exp` claim.

Comment: u answered my question actually sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is a [JSON Web Token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) (JWT), which—unless it's encrypted—can be decoded to inspect its contents (a web service to perform that task can be found [here](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io)).

Expiry claims are set with the `exp` property in the resulting JSON document.

Answer (score 1):

Expiry is 10 minutes. Its specified in the documentation : https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api/documentation/API-Reference-REST/BingVoiceRecognition

Bing Speech Team

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not have to login each time instead of using the `'Authorization': 'Bearer {TOKEN}'` header you could use the `'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{YOUR AZURE TOKEN}'` in order to not have to make a authorisation factory or more requests than necessary to the application and make it faster

NOTE: {TOKEN} is a JWT token like

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3BlZWNoLnBsYXRmb3JtLmJpbmcuY29tIiwic3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uLWlkIjoiZmFhZTNlYTkxNmI1NGMxZWEyODY4MDlhYTg3ZWE1MmUiLCJwcm9kdWN0LWlkIjoiQmluZy5TcGVlY2guUHJldmlldyIsImNvZ25pdGl2ZS1zZXJ2aWNlcy1lbmRwb2ludCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLmNvZ25pdGl2ZS5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2ludGVybmFsL3YxLjAvIiwiYXp1cmUtcmVzb3VyY2UtaWQiOiIiLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46bXMuY29nbml0aXZlc2VydmljZXMiLCJhdWQiOiJ1cm46bXMuc3BlZWNoIiwiZXhwIjoxNTAwODgxNjIzfQ.KdlCrIJ_H0jxs1yyeyYxYR7ucbLuFKT__ep7lGJmGbU
```

NOTE2: {YOUR AZURE TOKEN} is like `d5kals90935b40809dc6k38533c21e85` and you find it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/)

The request would look like this:

```
curl -v -X POST "https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=es-ES&locale=es-ES&format=simple&requestid=req_id" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: d5kals90935b40809dc6k38533c21e85" -H 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked'  -H 'Content-type: audio/wav; codec="audio/pcm"; samplerate=8000' --data-binary @"{BINAYFILE}.wav"
```